# Saving WorkItem - SaveFlags

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2010, workitem

in 2010 Beta 2 the new TFS SDK provides an overloaded method for WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags). SaveFlags is an enum with only 2 values: None and MergeLinks.  Does anybody know what the MergeLinks option actually does? Can't find it anywhere...  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN article(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff734890.aspx), it removes the errors of adding/removing links that have already been added/removed.

Comment: This is a more direct link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.saveflags.aspx

Comment: PMongomery's link is better because that page explains what the enum does. The direct link is not as clear, unfortunately.